# What is a substitute for ResourceFilter in Jersey 2.0

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm just wondering what is used in 2.0 instead of ResourceFilter found in Jersey 1.0

I have code to upgrade from 1.0 to 2.0. and can't find any replacement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DynamicFeature](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/DynamicFeature.html) (directly in JAX-RS 2.0) allows you to assign providers to resource methods in the similar way [ResourceFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ResourceFilter.html) does in Jersey 1.

See this [article](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/01/08/binding-jax-rs-providers-to-resource-methods/) that explains the concepts.